# Android show medias with old date on galery

Tags: mediastore, android-10.0, insert-query

I want to insert media in mediastore with a old date. Example ;

```
   val values = ContentValues()
    val extension = fileName.fileExtension()
    val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)
    values.apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, 1542628)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED, 1542628)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_TAKEN, 1542628983)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType)
        if (AndroidUtils.isAtLeastQ()) {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, getRelativePath(fileType))
        }
    }
    val url = resolver.insert(getMediaCollection(fileType, ExternalPrimary), values)
```

1542628983 = 19/11/2018 but after insert , media is shown on Today

How can I set a galery date on a media?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to save your bitmap into mediastore. You can get the bitmap with different methods. So after that, try this. Replace the values you want to modify with the new values.

```
fun saveBitmap(
    context: Context, bitmap: Bitmap?,
    displayName: String,
    directory: String
) {
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName)
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    values.put(
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + File.separator + File(directory).name
    )
    val uri = context.contentResolver
        .insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
    try {
        val stream =
            context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri!!)
        bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("TAG", "saveBitmapExc: ${e.message}")
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```